# Move a file and replace it by a symlink

Tags: shell-script, files, mv, ln

Can someone give me a command that would:

- move a file towards a new directory
- and leave a symlink in its old location towards its new one

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`mv` moves a file, and `ln -s` creates a symbolic link, so the basic task is accomplished by a script that executes these two commands:

```
#!/bin/sh
mv -- "$1" "$2"
ln -s -- "$2" "$1"
```

There are a few caveats. If the second argument is a directory, then `mv` would move the file into that directory, but `ln -s` would create a link to the directory rather than to the moved file.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
original="$1" target="$2"
if [ -d "$target" ]; then
  target="$target/${original##*/}"
fi
mv -- "$original" "$target"
ln -s -- "$target" "$original"
```

Another caveat is that the first argument to `ln -s` is the exact text of the symbolic link. It's relative to the location of the target, not to the directory where the command is executed. If the original location is not in the current directory and the target is not expressed by an absolute path, the link will be incorrect. In this case, the path needs to be rewritten. In this case, I'll create an absolute link (a relative link would be preferable, but it's harder to get right). This script assumes that you don't have file names that end in a newline character.

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
original="$1" target="$2"
if [ -d "$target" ]; then
  target="$target/${original##*/}"
fi
mv -- "$original" "$target"
case "$original" in
  */*)
    case "$target" in
      /*) :;;
      *) target="$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "$target")" && pwd)/${target##*/}"
    esac
esac
ln -s -- "$target" "$original"
```

If you have multiple files, process them in a loop.

```
#!/bin/sh
while [ $# -gt 1 ]; do
  eval "target=\${$#}"
  original="$1"
  if [ -d "$target" ]; then
    target="$target/${original##*/}"
  fi
  mv -- "$original" "$target"
  case "$original" in
    */*)
      case "$target" in
        /*) :;;
        *) target="$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "$target")" && pwd)/${target##*/}"
      esac
  esac
  ln -s -- "$target" "$original"
  shift
done
```

Comment: Thanks Gilles, for the script and the explanations. I'll try to understand that !

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer

Comment: To make this answer even more awesome, `rsync --remove-source-files` might be more informative to users who are moving a large file off a disk which may take some time.

Comment: I think you should call sh with -e so it breaks on errors, for example if you stop the mv command because a file already exists

Comment: `Another caveat is that the first argument to ln -s is the exact text of the symbolic link.` -- See the new-ish and awesome `ln --relative` option.

Comment: There are problems. First with ``target="$target/${original##*/}"`` if your original is for example "folder/" it causes complete removal of "folder/" from there. I would use just ``target="$target/`basename "${original}"`"``. Second problem with link creation and fix is ``ln -s -- "$target" "`realpath "$original"`"`` which removes last slash from "folder/".

Answer (score 2):

I generally use the this one-line function:

```
function ml() { mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")" && rsync -aP --no-links "$1" "$2" && ln -sf "$2" "$1" }
```

Usage is similar to mv or cp:

```
ml old_file target_dir/new_file_name
```

Breaking it down:

- `mkdir -p "$(dirname "$1")"` - create the destination directory if it does not already exist

  - `dirname "$1"` - get the directory component of the path (strip the filename)
- `rsync -aP --no-links "$1" "$2"` - copy the file over to the destination. Replace this with `mv "$1" "$2"` if both files are on the same filesystem for better performance.

  - `-a` - preserve ownership and all other permissions. You can tune this to only preserve the components you want.
  - `-P` - show progress.
  - `--no-links` - don't copy links--this means you can run this command as many times as you want on the same file, and you won't ever lose your file by accidentally overwriting your destination file with a symlink to itself.
- `ln -sf "$2" "$1"` - overwrite the old file with a symlink to the new file

  - `-s` - use symbolic links
  - `-f` - overwrite the old file

Comment: this would create a directory instead of renaming a file in case the second argument was not supposed to be a target directory

Answer (score 1):

Put this in .sh file and make it executable(`chmod +x filename`):

```
#!/bin/bash

mv "$1" "$2"
ln -s "$2" "$1"
```

Usage example:

```
./test.sh asdf otherdir/asdf
```

Note that this does no safety checks, etc. Depending on how complex is your task, this might be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, this works perfectly when applied on one file. But can you help me generalising this to two directories like this :

    `./test.sh .mozila/firefox/zotero/*/*.pdf MyBbliography/*.pdf`.

The `*` does not seem to be working with your `test.sh`. Have you got a workaround ? Thx

Comment: @kadok MatthewRock's script only works for a single file, and the target must be an absolute path or else the source must be in the current directory.

Comment: Also, it won't work if $1 is a file but $2 is a directory.